# noob “Duplicate instance declarations” (again)(again)

Tags: haskell

(re post with a better example) with a naïve OO head...we go....

```
> class Drink a where

> class DrinkWithCaffeine a where

> class Fizzy a where

> class Still a where

> class Cola a where

> instance (Drink a) => DrinkWithCaffeine a
> instance (Drink a) => Fizzy a
> instance (Drink a) => Still a

> instance (Fizzy a) => Cola a
> instance (DrinkWithCaffeine a) => Cola a
```

and ghc goes

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
    instance forall (k :: BOX) (a :: k). Fizzy a => Cola a
    instance forall (k :: BOX) (a :: k). DrinkWithCaffeine a => Cola a
```

and you look it up...and there is a solution using witness types, that I could probably get to work BUT....I don't understand what the problem?

allegedly the compiler matches the right hand side and bla bla...?

I don't understand....I think I'm saying...if I have a type of typeclass Dog...then its also of typeclass Animal...so if I call methods foo etc then this is how to do it (in terms of a Dog)

I'm missing something

Comment: Please choose a better title. What is the title of your next related question going to be? "noob ... (again)(again)(again)"?

Comment: ignore this whole thing for the moment, I don't understand my own question....how do I delete the question?

Comment: Type classes are not OO classes. For instance, the Haskell type system has no subtyping, which is crucial in OOP type systems: most other statically typed functional languages follow the same approach as Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it is that what `instance (Fizzy a) => Cola a` really means is, any `a` is a `Cola`, but fail if that `a` isn't a `Fizzy`. The context (`Fizzy a`) isn't taken into consideration when determining duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

please ignore my question, I didn't read a previous reply properly...if I do what I'm supposed to

```
> class Drink a where

> class (Drink a) => DrinkWithCaffeine a where

> class (Drink a) => Fizzy a where

> class (Drink a) => Still a where

> class (DrinkWithCaffeine a,Fizzy a) => Cola a where
```

it works.